# code produces a 2d histogram but the results dont match with hist2d

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to write a histogram builder to construct a 2d histogram for my assignment work. This is [my code][1]:

```
def Build2DHistogramClassifier(X1,X2,T,B,x1min,x1max,x2min,x2max):
 HF=np.zeros((B,B),dtype='int');#initialising a empty array of integer type
 HM=np.zeros((B,B),dtype='int');
 bin_row_indices=(np.round(((B-1)*(X1-x1min)/(x1max-x1min)))).astype('int32');"""this logic decides which bin the value goes into"""
 bin_column_indices=(np.round(((B-1)*(X2-x2min)/(x2max-x2min)))).astype('int32');"""np.round-->applies the formula to all the values in the array"""
 for i,(r,c) in enumerate(zip(bin_row_indices, bin_column_indices)):
     """enumerate-->if we put array or list into it gives output with index/count i """
     if T[i]=='Female':
         HF[r,c]+=1;
     else:
         HM[r,c]+=1;
return [HF, HM]
```

but the problem is that the results( count in each bin) i am getting is not matching the what i get from using hist2d function in numpy( i passed the same bin size)

i am sorry if my code is not in the right format. Please click on the hyperlink to a gist i created with the same code.

what is the mistake in my code?

how do i correct it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

By rounding when assigning to bins you are treating the bins as bin centers. The numpy convention is to use them as bin edges.

Remove the two calls to `round()` from your code and change `B-1` to `B`. You should now get the same results with your function and with `np.histogram2d`.